# can't find google smart app in home control

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

when I run the Google smart home [demo](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs), I have a problem at `25.Find your app in the list of providers.` The result is that I can’t find my APP in Home control use the Google Pixel device.
I am sure that:
1、I use the same google account to create the project in web and login in google home App on Google Pixel, and I launch the test in 30 mins which mean that the test shouldn’t be expired. 
2、I have done the command "gactions test --action_package PACKAGE_NAME --project PROJECT_ID"

Could you any body gave me some suggestions?  I have sticked it for more than two weeks.

[image]

Comment: Does it work in the simulator?

Comment: No. when I run it in the simulator than response  "sorry the agent returned an empty TTS".

Comment: Have you done integration with Google Assistance in api.ai ?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I used the Actions SDK to develop this demo.

Answer (score 0):

The Google smart home demo you mentioned is to help you build web service to process Google smart home requests. After building web service and host it on some public URL, you have to specify this URL in your action.json.

Also you need to build your OAuth 2.0 server and specify it in project setting in AoG console.

Then after executing"gactions test --action_package PACKAGE_NAME --project PROJECT_ID", you shold see your app [test]YOUR_APP_NAME in the add devices section.

Please check if you miss any part above and your gactions command runs without error messages.

Good luck~